# Keyframed Objects Clipping Through Each Other

Tags: armature, physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I am very new to Blender and have made a scene where a mannequin (animated and downloaded from mixamo) is falling through a tunnel. A basic falling animation has been applied to the mannequin via mixkit.co and I have also animated the mannequin to follow the path of the tunnel, keyframing the offset to have it fly past the camera. However, as the mannequin is falling its hands and feet often clip through the tunnel (screenshots attached). Is there a way for the mannequin to interact with the edges of the tunnel?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Jake

SCREENSHOTS:

Foot Clipping: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv44u.jpg

Hand Clipping: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqjGS.jpg

Viewport: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpFnb.jpg

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to Check the **Collision Margin** and then increase the margin for the tunnel in the rigid body animation tab.That might solve it.

[image]